# How pH paper works

Tags: acid-base

Please tell me how a pH paper works. How does it decide whether the solution is an acid or a base on the basis of ions formed and how it can determine its concentration. How does it indicate an acid or a base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a piece of paper with one or a couple of these coated on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator

Indicators are dye molecules that change colour depending on the pH of a solution.

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a little more detail here about how this works? At the moment this is in danger of being flagged as low quality for being too brief.